# asp.net get filename of a file inside the specific folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good morning!

I would like to ask some help from you guys on how do i do this problem. I'm using asp.net and my problem is on getting the list of filename inside the folder. Is there a function on this? I tried this on console apps there's a function like GetFileName. Hope somebody could help me on this.

Thank you so much.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Systm.IO.Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles.aspx)

Comment: thanks david,but i think this only applicable on windows application or console.

Comment: hi david, my mistake. You're right i just confirmed that also in asp.net is also applicable this function. Thank you so much for the quick reply.